# How to identify if the selected text in JTextPane are of different sizes?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am developing a editor where I have a combobox for font size. User can use it to alter the text size.

I have also implemented the caret listener which tells me the size of selected text and updates the combobox accordingly. Now if the user selects the text of two different sizes I want to populate blank value in Combobox. But I am unable to do that with Caret listener as It gives me size of the first text.

Eg: If my text is "HI". Here H is of size 12 and I is of size 22. Now when I select "HI" caret listener gives me the value of either 12 or 22.

Here is the sample code:

```
StyledDocument doc = pane.getStyledDocument();
MutableAttributeSet fontSizeStyle = ((StyledEditorKit)pane.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes();
int fontSize = StyleConstants.getFontSize(fontSizeStyle);
```

Comment: So you need to write a loop that iterates through all the characters of the selected text. If all the sizes are the same you display that size. As soon as you find a different size you stop looping and display blank.

Comment: Hi I am new to Swing. So need your help here. I am able to get the selected text by using pane.getSelectedText() and iterating it to get each character, but how do I find out its size?

Comment: Ok I found the solution now. Posting it below

Answer (score 2):

Below code would loop through the selected text in Jtextpane and get each character's size.

```
String selectedText = pane.getSelectedText();
int k = pane.getSelectionStart();

for(int i=0; i< selectedText.length(); i++) {
   AttributeSet fontSize = doc.getCharacterElement(k).getAttributes();                       
   System.out.println("fontSize:"+StyleConstants.getFontSize(fontSize));
   k++;
}
```

Comment: +1 but you should use getSelectionStart()/getSelectionEnd() for the offset

Comment: Yes I forgot to add 1 line. Modified the answer now

Comment: To be precise no need to do k++. It should be k=doc.getCharacterElement(k).getEndOffset() and there should be check whether k is bigger than selection